# Missing edges when stacking multiple geometries and using EdgesHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js so I am not sure whether I have made a mistake or my approach is wrong in the first place.

Check out my demo (use left and right arrow to navigate around):
http://www.ralphunden.de/files/kloetze/index.htm

The problem is that "inner edges" are not showing up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i01fE.png

The idea is to achieve a "blocky" look by using solid shapes with highlighted borders.

- The best approach I have found is to use a BoxGeometry with a basic material and adding the outline with EdgesHelper.
- The passed parameter shape is just a list of coordinates.
- I am also not sure about adding the resulting meshes together like this (I do this so I can remove it from the scene comfortably later and it hasn't been a problem so far).

Here's the code:

```
function draw_shape(shape, offset, colour) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh();
        for (var i = 0; i < shape.length; i++) {
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: colour });
            var tmp = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            tmp.position.x = shape[i][0] * BLOCKSIZE - offset[0];
            tmp.position.y = shape[i][1] * BLOCKSIZE - offset[1];
            tmp.position.z = shape[i][2] * BLOCKSIZE - offset[2];
            mesh.add(tmp)
            var outline = new THREE.EdgesHelper(tmp, 0x000000);
            outline.material.linewidth = 2;
            mesh.add(outline);
        }
        return mesh;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I faked it out like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(BLOCKSIZE - 1 , BLOCKSIZE - 1, BLOCKSIZE - 1);
```

This means I made the boxes smaller by 1 which introduces a small gap to the nex box. This works and was something I tried early on but it looked very bad because the gap was too noticeable.

Then it struck me to try it again and at the same time increase BLOCKSIZE considerably so that the gap is be relatively smaller. At the same time I moved the camera further away by the same factor. (Ie. I increased BLOCKSIZE from 30 to 90 and moved the camera from about 200 to 600).

The result is satisfactory.